# Folland's proof of open mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The Open Mapping Theorem states:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. If $T \in L(X, Y)$ is surjective, then $T$ is open.

Below is a part of the proof by Folland:

> Divind both sides by $2$, we conclude that there exists $r > 0$ such that if $\|y\| <r$ then $y \in \overline{T(B_1)}$. Since $T$ commutes with dilations, it follows that if $\|y\| < r2^{-n}$, then $y \in \overline{T(B_{2^{-n}})}$. Suppose $\|y\| < r/2$; we can find $x_1 \in B_{1/2}$ such that $\|y - Tx_1\| < r/4$, and proceed inductively, we can find $x_n \in B_{2^{-n}}$ such that $\|y-\sum_1^n Tx_j\| < r2^{-n-1}$. Since $X$ is complete, every absolutely convergent series converges, hence the series $\sum_1^\infty x_n$ converges, say to $x$. But then $\|x\| < \sum_1^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$ and $y = Tx$. In other words, $T(B_1)$ contains all $y$ with $\|y \| < r/2$, so we are done.

I'm confused about:

1. I'm not aware why the $T_{x_j}$ terms are summed up, and
2. Why is $\sum_1^\infty x_n$ convergent? I'm not aware why $\sum_1^\infty |x_n|$ converges...

I probably missed something obvious and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How else would the induction work?

We have $x_1\in B_{1/2}$ with $\|y-Tx_1\|<r/4$. What next? Well, what Folland does is now consider $y_1=y-Tx_1$. Because $\|y_1\|<r\cdot 2^{-2}$, $y_1\in\overline{T(B_{2^{-2}})}$. So, there should be some $x_2\in B_{2^{-2}}$ with $\|y_1-Tx_2\|<r\cdot 2^{-2-1}$. So: $\|y-Tx_1-Tx_2\|=\|y-\sum_{j=1}^2T(x_j)\|$ is smaller than $r/8$. Now put $y_2:=y-\sum_{j=1}^2T(x_j)$. We deduce $y_2\in\overline{T(B_{2^{-3}})}$ so there is $x_3\in B_{2^{-3}}$ with: $$\|y-\sum_{j=1}^3T(x_j)\|=\|y-\sum_{j=1}^2T(x_j)-T(x_3)\|=\|y_2-T(x_3)\|<r\cdot 2^{-3-1}$$Et cetera. The summation of the $T(x_j)$ terms naturally arises from the inductive process.

Intuitively, $x_1$ is a rough stab at where $y$ is; $x_2$ is a smaller correction term, and so on, and adding up the ever-smaller correction terms leads you to a *small* solution $x$ to $Tx=y$.

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$ is convergent because: $$\sum_{j=N}^M\|x_j\|<\sum_{j=N}^M2^{-j}<2^{-(N-1)}$$For all $M>N\in\Bbb N$ and the right hand side can be made as small as you please. So, the partial sums $\sum_{j=1}^Mx_j$ form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: no worries!  @sam2018